# What is the right notion of morphisms between strict monoidal categories? [Awodey, Exercise 4.5.9]

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

In Awodey's book "Category Theory", a *strict monoidal category* is defined as (Definition 4.9):

> A *strict monoidal category* is a category $\textbf{C}$ equipped with a binary operation $\otimes: \textbf{C} \times \textbf{C} \to \textbf{C}$ which is functorial and associative, $A \otimes (B \otimes C) = (A \otimes B) \otimes C$, together with a distinguished object $I$ that acts as a unit, $I \otimes C = C = C \otimes I$.

As noted in [Strict monoidal categories, the definition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784993/strict-monoidal-categories-the-definition), this condition will need to hold both for objects and morphisms, so let's assume that for now.

Awodey goes on to define the category $\textbf{Ord}_\text{fin}$, the objects of which are the finite ordinal numbers, represented in the usual way as sets via $0 = \emptyset, n+1 = \{ 0, \ldots, n \}$, with $+$ as the binary operation and $0$ as the distinguished object, and the of the category arrows are all functions between the ordinals represented as sets. It is easy to see that the objects form a set satisfying the Peano axioms, and that $+$ and $0$ form a commutative monoid. It's also easy to verify that $+$ is functorial, by setting $((f: m \to n) + (g: k \to \ell))(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x < m \\ g(x - m) + n & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Exercise 4.5.9 then asks me to prove that $\textbf{Ord}_\text{fin}$ is the free monoidal category on one object.

My assumption is that we will have to show the following universal mapping property:
Let $U = \{ * \}$ be a set with one element. Then (i) there is a map $i: U \to (\textbf{Ord}_\text{fin})_0$ picking an object, and (ii)
let $(\textbf{C}, \otimes, I)$ be a monoidal category and $f: U \to \textbf{C}_0$ a function from $U$ to the objects of $\textbf{C}$ (i.e., we pick an object of $\textbf{C}$). Then there is an arrow $\overline{f}: \textbf{Ord}_\text{fin} \to \textbf{C}$ such that $|\overline{f}|$ (the part of $\overline{f}$ that operates on objects) satisfies $f = |\overline{f}| \circ i$, in analogy with the UMP of free monoids (for instance).

From my reading of the definitions, I would assume that an arrow of monoidal categories would, at the very least, be a functor such that $f(m + n) = f(m) \otimes f(n)$ and $f(0) = I$.

With this assumption, defining $i$ is straightforward (pick $i(*) := 1$), and it is also easy to define $|\overline{f}|(n) = \otimes_{i=1}^n f(*)$. My problem is that I don't see how to define $\overline{f}$ such that it is actually a *functor*: it seems that for any two finite ordinals $m, n$, there is at least one map from $m$ to $n$, except if $m \neq 0$, $n=0$ -- indeed, we can always take the map $z(x) = 0$

But for a given strict monoidal category, I don't see why there should always be a morphism from, say, $A \otimes A$ to $A$ for some object $A$ at all. But that would mean that I would not be able to define $\overline{f}(z: 2 \to 1)$, meaning that I wouldn't be able to make $\overline{f}$ a functor.

What mistake am I making? Am I using the wrong notion of arrow, or is there in fact a way to prove that there is always an arrow between $\bigotimes^m A$ and $\bigotimes^n A$, where $\bigotimes^k A = \otimes_{i=1}^k A$?

Comment: What edition are you using? There is no exercise 4.5.9 in my edition. (Generally speaking, *always* specify the edition when you quote a book.)

Comment: Oh right - I'm using the second edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to the update, rather it addresses more the original post. $\def\Mon{\mathrm{Mon}} \def\SMonCat{\mathrm{StrictMonCat}} \def\Set{\mathrm{Set}}$

Let $\SMonCat$ denote the category of (say small) strict monoidal categories together with strict monoidal functors.
The left adjoint of the functor $(C\mapsto C_0):\SMonCat\to\Set$ is given by simply taking the free monoid over a set and regarding it as a discrete monoidal category. You can verify this directly.

Other way to see it is to observe that $\SMonCat\to\Set$ factors through the category of monoids, and check that the functor $\SMonCat\to\Mon$ has as left adjoint the functor that regards a monoid as a discrete category (so a monoid is the free strict monoidal category over itself). Then the left adjoint of $\SMonCat\to\Set$ is first go from sets to monoids and then include into $\SMonCat$.

There may be a mistake in the book can't find exercise 4.5.9 in my second edition, either. I haven't considered lax monoidal functors instead of strict monoidal ones, but I may check what happens later. It is weird, nevertheless, because at least in my edition there is no mention of monoidal functors of any kind.

Comment: I see - the left adjoint gives the actual free functor here, so it's clear that the ordinals are not, in fact, free. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Partial progress: it seems that the construction of the functor as outlined above faces an insurmountable obstruction.

Consider the category $\textbf{M}$ whose objects are words on $\{0, 1\}$, and $u \to v$ exactly when $u$ is a subword of $v$. Take $\otimes$ to be concatenation, and $I$ to be the empty word. It is easy check that $\textbf{M}$ is a strict monoidal category - as a category, it's a poset, $I \otimes x = x \otimes I = x$ is clear, and if $u$ is a subword of $u'$ and $v$ a subword of $v'$, $uv$ is a subword of $u'v'$.

Now, note that by the construction outlined above, with $f(*) = 0$, we have $\overline{f}(n) = 0^n$. If $f$ was a functor, there would have to be an arrow $\overline{f}(z: 2 \to 1) = \overline{f}(2) \to \overline{f}(1) = 0^2 \to 0^1$, i.e., $00$ would have to be a subword of $0$, which is clearly not the case.

This still leaves open the question if there is another construction for $\overline{f}$ that makes it a functor, which is why I'm leaving the question open.